# How do I create a third column with the column header where a value was found?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to look through the columns of df2 for the values contained in df1['Part No']. I need to add a new col to df1 with the column header where the value was found.

```
data1 = {"Part No": ['100', '101', '102'],
        "Desc": ["Blue", "Green", "Red"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1 = df1[['Part No', 'Desc']]

data2 = {"col1": ['100', '101', 'a', 'b'], 
        "col2": ['102', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 
        "col3": ['999', '1', '2', '0' ]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df1)
print('\r')
print(df2)
print('\r')

#My expected output:
data3 = {"Part No": ['100', '101', '102'],
        "Desc": ["Blue", "Green", "Red"], 
         "New Col" : ['col1', 'col1', 'col2']}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
df3 = df3[['Part No', 'Desc', 'New Col']]
print(df3)
```

Comment: Can a value ever be found in more than one column in `df2`?

Comment: No, not in this particular case.  The values would only appear in one column in df2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pythonic code and all mighty `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np    

df1['new col'] = df1['Part No'].apply(lambda x: df2.columns[list(zip(*np.where(df2==x)))[0][1]] )
```

output is:

```
Part No Desc    new col
0   100 Blue    col1
1   101 Green   col1
2   102 Red     col2
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly!  Thank you!  I was really struggling with getting the column value into that third column.

Comment: this solution worked perfectly on my test set of data.  However, when I use it with a larger data set, I get IndexError: list index out of range.  In real life, df1 has about 5000 entries.  df2.columns have only a handful of entries per column.  Any suggestions on how to fix this index issue?  I've been trying different approaches all morning to solve the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: this code assumes there is always a match, if there is none then you should get an error, perhaps using a try catch statement

Comment: Ahhhh..thank you.  I'm still learning, so this is helpful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

By using `unstack` on `df2`, with a `reset_index` and a `rename`, you can have on one row each value of `df2` and the name of the column it was in:

```
(df2.unstack().reset_index(name='Part No')[['level_0','Part No']]
       .rename(columns={'level_0':'New Col'}))
# if you print this, it looks like:
   New Col Part No
0     col1     100
1     col1     101
2     col1       a
3     col1       b
4     col2     102
5     col2       c
6     col2       d
7     col2       e
8     col3     999
9     col3       1
10    col3       2
11    col3       0
```

With `merge` between `df1` and `df2` manipulated as above such as:

```
df3 = df1.merge((df2.unstack()
                    .reset_index(name='Part No')[['level_0','Part No']]
                    .rename(columns={'level_0':'New Col'}) ) ,how='left')
```

then you get `df3`:

```
  Part No   Desc New Col
0     100   Blue    col1
1     101  Green    col1
2     102    Red    col2
```

EDIT: @DSM provided another solution to manipulate `df2` to get the same result, using `melt` instead of `unstack`, `reset_index` and `rename`:

```
df2.melt(value_name="Part No", var_name="New Col")
```

and then,

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.melt(value_name="Part No", var_name="New Col") ,how='left')
```

gives the expected output.

Comment: Ehh, I added an answer but it was basically yours, but using `(df2.melt(value_name="Part No", var_name="New Col")` instead of your unstack/reset_index/rename part.

Comment: @DSM I saw and upvoted it :) I did not know about `melt` so I'm happy that I learnt this today!

Comment: This is also a great solution!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DSM added you solution in my answer. Thanks